# Progress bar for upload not working again for Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I recently discovered that my upload for an already existing php, Javascript, jQuery, bootstrap application stopped working. I have been trying to resolve this issue for over a week now. On the javascript console I am getting this error
: main.js:604 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clipresize is not a function. Please any assistance will be of great assistance. I was thinking that the many references to various Jquery files could be causing this error or is it that all browsers have been recently upgraded not to support some snippets being referenced. I am confused.
 The application codes are below:

add.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]--><!-- start: HEAD -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>upload</title>
<!-- start: META -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' 
content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-
scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="" name="description">
<meta content="" name="author">
<!-- end: META -->
<!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fonts/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main-responsive.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-colorpalette.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme_light.css" type="text/css" 
id="skin_color">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/print.css" type="text/css" 
media="print">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/validate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker.css">        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-
16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="../js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery.icheck.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap-colorpalette.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/main.js"></script> 

<script src="../js/index.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/ajax.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/validations.js"></script> 
<!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.inputlimiter.1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/form-elements.js"></script>

    <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            Main.init();
            FormElements.init();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY --> 
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            Main.init();
            UIModals.init();
        });
    </script> 
   <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY --> 
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            Main.init();
            Index.init();
        });
    </script>

   .......
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.css">

 .................

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_app').submit(function(e) {    

  var value =  manage_form(); 

  if(value==false)
  {
    return false;
  }else{

   e.preventDefault();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
            //target:   '#targetLayer', 
            beforeSubmit: function() {
              $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, 
      percentComplete){ 
                $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + 
      percentComplete +' %</div>')

            },

            success:function (data){
            $('#modal1').openModal();
                $('#loader-icon').hide();
                $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                var res = data.split("~");
                $('#mode7').html('<a href="add.php?flag=edit&id='+res[1]+'" 
     class="btn light-green modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-
     green btn-flat">Okay</a>');
                document.getElementById('row_id').value = res[1];
                document.getElementById('row1_id').value = res[1];
                document.getElementById('package').value = res[0];
                //document.getElementById('process_id').html = data;
                //$('#mode7').html('<a href="add.php?
    flag=edit&id='+res[1]+'" class="btn light-green modal-action modal-close 
    waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Okay</a>');

            },

            resetForm: true 
        }); 
        return false; 

   }
        }); 

    });
```

and  the "main.js" script that throws the error is below:

```
             //Window Resize Function
var runWIndowResize = function(func, threshold, execAsap) {
    //wait until the user is done resizing the window, then execute
    $(window).clipresize(function() {
        runElementsPosition();
    });
};
```

Comment: Did someone remove Flexslider? Or change its location?

Comment: Sorry about that sir, but I did not build the application, I am only maintaining it. Like earlier this year despite a couple of error thrown in the javascript console by non available css and a javascript code, the code still worked. The upload bar was actually moving, but now it stopped. Sir, or should I find out about Flexslider before moving on? Although I saw something similar to the issue I am having on this link https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uncaught-typeerror-sticky-is-not-a-function

Comment: The error is realted to Flexslider, so I would start there.

Comment: The application likely uses maybe some js linked to a Flexslider, but there is no reference to a flexslider in this application.

Comment: Sir, I really wish I could post all assets related to this application or better still let me give a link to the application. Which will you prefer?

Comment: Were there any changes to your code prior to the problem?

Comment: Rollback your changes and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: I have rolled back the changes and still my upload(submit) button isn't responding, its just hanging and nothing seems to be happening

Comment: Do you have the same error in the console?

Comment: Yes sir. The error is actually these below:                                    
   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clipresize is not a function
    at runWIndowResize (main.js:604)
    at Object.init (main.js:736)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (add_3.php:111)
    at fire (jquery.min.js:2913)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3025)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:398)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.min.js:93)

Comment: This is the error part of the main.js as indicated by the javascript console:                                                                                                      
          //Window Resize Function
 var runWIndowResize = function(func, threshold, execAsap) {
  //wait until the user is done resizing the window, then execute
  $(window).clipresize(function() {
   runElementsPosition();
  });
 };

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get my progress bar working and all the assets uploaded to the required folder by removing a mailing library called Php Mailer in my php submit script. The Php mailer library was failing in my application and I discovered that it was throwing up a blank or null output which was causing my application to break by not responding to the submit button. And broken libraries at times are the reason for which many formerly functioning web applications are said to stop functioning. The solution many times will be to update the required libraries or to remove them and find a way to tweak the application to work without those libraries. Thanks